# TWaitObjectThread_Notify (Cannot get default config platform!)

Tags: visual-studio-2019, incredibuild

I use IncrediBuild v.9.6.4 with CMake and VS 2019. I have a solution with more than 1000 projects (c++ , cs). The building of this solution works fine on the most of computers(Win 10) but on one computer it fails very often with this error:

```
--------------------Build System Error------------------------------------

 Fatal error:
    Failed to notify object at 0x074CD910, class is TWaitObjectThread_Notify
    Cannot get default config platform!

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Because it fails very often but only on one computer I assume it is a problem with the configuration of IB or OS. Do you have an experience with this kind of fatal error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the root cause for the problem you describe is related to a specific MSBuild output parsing issue in previous versions of Incredibuild. A similar issue was already fixed in latest version, so installing the latest version may fix it.

If this still doesn’t help and the problem persists, suggesting to send build monitor output with the most detailed log level to Incredibuild's support team (support *at* incredibuild.com).